# Convert Wikipedia dump to text using python -m gensim.scripts.make_wiki

Tags: python, wikipedia, gensim

I want to use gensim to convert Wikipedia dump to plain text using `python -m gensim.scripts.make_wiki` script.

I use it as :

```
python -m gensim.scripts.make_wiki ./enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 ./results
```

gives me an error at the end:

```
2016-04-06 20:43:46,471 : INFO : storing corpus in Matrix Market format to ./results/_bow.mm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/scripts/make_wiki.py", line 88, in <module>
    MmCorpus.serialize(outp + '_bow.mm', wiki, progress_cnt=10000) # another ~9h
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/corpora/indexedcorpus.py", line 89, in serialize
    offsets = serializer.save_corpus(fname, corpus, id2word, progress_cnt=progress_cnt, metadata=metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/corpora/mmcorpus.py", line 49, in save_corpus
    return matutils.MmWriter.write_corpus(fname, corpus, num_terms=num_terms, index=True, progress_cnt=progress_cnt, metadata=metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/matutils.py", line 486, in write_corpus
    mw = MmWriter(fname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/matutils.py", line 436, in __init__
    self.fout = utils.smart_open(self.fname, 'wb+') # open for both reading and writing
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 111, in smart_open
NotImplementedError: unknown file mode wb+
```

Does anybody know what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the command line script, but the following works for me -

```
def parse_wiki(wiki_bz_file):
    output = open('./wiki_text_dump.txt', 'w')
    i = 0
    wiki = WikiCorpus(wiki_bz_file, lemmatize=False, dictionary={}) #vocab dict not needed
    for text in wiki.get_texts():
        output.write(u.listToStr(chunk) + '\n')
        i = i + 1
        if i%50000 == 0:
            logger.info("Saved " + str(i) + " articles")
    output.close()
    logger.info("Finished Saved " + str(i) + " articles")
    return
```

Comment: when I use this code I get the error NameError: name 'u' is not defined